# Docker on WSL and Testcontainers instead of Docker Desktop: docker-machine executable was not found on PATH

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, wsl-2, testcontainers

I installed WSL on Windows 10 and installed Docker on it like this

```
wsl
sudo apt update 
sudo apt install docker.io -y
wsl docker
doskey docker=wsl docker
wsl docker -v
Docker version 24.0.5, build 24.0.5-0ubuntu1~20.04.1
```

I run automated tests with testconteiners in Idea and automated tests don't see Docker running.

I got an error

```
 o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : Loaded org.testcontainers.dockerclient.NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy from ~/.testcontainers.properties, will try it first
2023-09-04 16:19:11.678  INFO 17864 --- [           main] .t.d.DockerMachineClientProviderStrategy : docker-machine executable was not found on PATH ([C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin, C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin, C:\Program Files\Docker, c:\oraclex64\product\12.1.0\client\bin,  C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath, C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath, C:\WINDOWS\system32, C:\WINDOWS, C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem, C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\, C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\, C:\Program Files\PuTTY\, C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin, C:\utils, C:\utils\confluent-7.0.1, C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin, C:\Gradle\gradle-6.8\bin, C:\Program Files\Git\cmd, C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.2.3\bin, C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.3\bin, C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.2.1\bin])
2023-09-04 16:19:41.696 ERROR 17864 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : Could not find a valid Docker environment. Please check configuration. Attempted configurations were:
2023-09-04 16:19:41.696 ERROR 17864 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       :     NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception TimeoutException (Timeout waiting for result with exception). Root cause NoSuchFileException (\\.\pipe\docker_engine)
2023-09-04 16:19:41.696 ERROR 17864 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       :     NpipeSocketClientProviderStrategy: failed with exception TimeoutException (Timeout waiting for result with exception). Root cause NoSuchFileException (\\.\pipe\docker_engine)
2023-09-04 16:19:41.696 ERROR 17864 --- [           main] o.t.d.DockerClientProviderStrategy       : As no valid configuration was found, execution cannot continue
```

What should I do to make testcontainer to see Docker

P.S I can't use Docker Desktop

Comment: I'd recommend you to raise this issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA and share a project sample for testing